# How to stop ArcGIS Pro report from inserting cover page?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, reports

I have a simple report I've designed in ArcGIS Pro that outputs a handful of fields in a table for each selected feature in a point layer (see image below). Everything works as expected with the table itself and the formatting all looks correct.

However, Pro always inserts a cover page that contains only the Report Header no matter what I've tried. Turning off the Report Header has no effect on the layout; Pro just inserts a blank page instead and then starts the table on Page 2.

Is there a way to turn off this cover page by default in a report? It's obviously possible to tell Pro not to print this page in the PDF export options, but that's not ideal for reports that will be generated numerous times in the future.

[image]